# IIS Mod-Rewrite QUERY_STRING/QSA problems

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite

We use IIS Mod-Rewrite from MicoNovae for our IIS rewrites on Windows 2003.

We use the RewriteRule command, for example:
http://www.site.com/section35/page1/tiling-tools/
becomes:
http://www.site.com/search.asp?section=35&page=1&model=tiling-tools

I now have a situation where I need to append the querystring to the re-written URL, for example:
http://www.site.com/section35/page1/tiling-tools/?myid=dskajh34kjhsvkjh34
need to become
http://www.site.com/search.asp?section=35&page=1&model=tiling-tools&myid=dskajh34kjhsvkjh34

My rules are:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^/section([^/]+)/page([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/$ /search_results.asp?section=$1&page=$2&model=$3 [L]
```

I've tried the following, without success:

```
RewriteRule ^/section([^/]+)/page([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/$ /search_results.asp?section=$1&page=$2&model=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^/section([^/]+)/page([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/$ /search_results.asp?section=$1&page=$2&model=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Suggestions will be appreciated ('cos it's driving me mad!)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the query string appending, I'm not even sure your rewrite rule is working at all?!?  I would suggest to use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/section([0-9]+)/page([0-9]+)/(.*)/    /search_results.asp?section=$1&page=$2&model=$3    [NC,L,QSA]
```

The NC flag makes your rewrite rule non-case sensitive and the QSA flag adds the query string you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marco. Turns out that adding QSA was working all along, but other code was causing the problem! Thanks also for the NC tip...